# import my scrapy script throwing cannot import on method

Tags: python, import, scrapy

Im at a mental block of how I can import my python class currently saved as `Scrapese.py`.

```
import scrapy

class Scrapese(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape-se'
    seach_engine = [
        'se1.com',
        'se2.com',
    ]

    def parse(self, seach_engine, site_to_parse, page_start, page_end, response):
        site = str(seach_engine+site_to_parse)
        if site_to_parse == seach_engine[0]:
            print("executing against se1!")
        elif site_to_parse == searh_engine[1]:
            print("executing against se2!")
        else:
            print("Something bad happened.")
```

I keep trying to typical:

```
from Scrapese import parse
```

but it says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can't import `Scrapese.parse` directly, but you can import the class using `from Scrapese import Scrapese`, create an instance of that class and then invoke `parse` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrapese` is the name of a Python module in which you define a class also called `Scrapese`.

The line `from Scrapese import parse` will cause the Python interpreter to try importing a module called `Scrapese` and looking in that for an object `parse`.

What you probably want to do is the following:

```
# Scrapese.py

class Scrapese(object):
    def parse(self):
        pass

# main.py

from Scrapese import Scrapese

o = Scrapese()
o.parse()
```

This will cause the Python interpreter to make the `Scrapese` class definition available within another script (`main.py`), which you can then instantiate and use for parsing.

Comment: What if i just want to call the file scrapese as needed?

Comment: @Jshee What do you mean?

Comment: Nvm, i think you clarifed this. Thanks @tagc !

Comment: One further question, if you dont mind. How can instantiate `parse` method and call `seach_engine` param for the second url?

Comment: That's a whole other kettle of fish. The way you've implemented `Scrapese` seems to be riddled with problems, such as the fact that `parse` accepts something as a parameter that shadows an instance variable (most likely you just wanted to use the instance variable). You've also misspelt `search_engine` multiple times in multiple different ways. It's best if you raise these issues as new questions.